# setbase(8) and std::cout<<std::oct

Tags: c++, iomanip

Whats the difference between `std::cout<<std::setbase(8)<<32;` and `std::cout<<std::oct<<32;` Are they equivalent?

And also, what is the purpose of `std::cout.oct`??

Comment: I can't believe they included `oct` but not `bin`

Comment: @Charles Salvia: Octal output/Incput has been with C since the beginning. Binary Output/Input has seemed redundant as there is a simple transition to Oct (3 binary digits) or Hex (4 binary digits)

Comment: I still agree with Charles that it would be nice if there was a bin flag.  It makes bit-bashing and bit-mask related work much easier to debug.

Comment: @Charles: `setbase` also only accepts 8, 10, or 16, so it's entirely consistent that they do not support binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**std::oct**    Sets the basefield format flag for the str stream to oct.

**std::setbase** Sets the basefield format flag to one of its possible values: hex, dec or oct depending on the value of the base parameter.

I think the big difference is that setbase takes an argument so you could pass it a variable containing the numerical base you want.  Instead of having a bunch of if statements to check the variable and use dec, oct or hex.

I'm not sure about std::cout.oct though.

Comment: `std::ostream::oct` can be used as a mask to check if it the `oct` bit is set.  Like: `if (std::cout.flags() & std::cout.oct)`.  Whereas `std::oct` is simply an IO stream manipulator function meant to be inserted into a stream.